# Is there a way to access Dynamic Navigation settings with the Google Search Appliance API?

Tags: google-search-appliance

I would like to use the GSA API to read and write the Dynamic Navigation settings.  From the [API documentation](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/acapi_protocol/acapi_protocol.html#1096044), it looks like this isn't possible.  Screen scraping is another option, but most of the page content is built client-side with JavaScript, which makes normal command-line screen scraping very difficult.

[image]

Is there an undocumented feature of the API perhaps, or some other way to access settings that aren't covered in the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unofficial [gsa-admin-toolkit](https://code.google.com/p/gsa-admin-toolkit/) project has a `gsa_admin.py` script which can import and export configuration files, and, most importantly, re-sign them.  Before, editing an exported config file wasn't an option because they contain a checksum or hash.  They get corrupted when edited.

This tool allows editing of the config file, re-signing, and importing back to the GSA.